# Tensorflow pip built from source fails on 'import tensorflow'

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

Built tensorflow 0.7 from source on Ubuntu 15.10, Cuda 7.5, cudnn 4.0, python 2.7.  Bazel build and pip package generation OK.  pip install ok.  Python script "import tensorflow" fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keith/Desktop/tf1.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n,tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"z\n\x10TensorShapeProto\x12-\n\x03\x64im\x18\x02 \x03(\x0b\x32 .tensorflow.TensorShapeProto.Dim\x12\x14\n\x0cunknown_rank\x18\x03 \x01(\x08\x1a!\n\x03\x44im\x12\x0c\n\x04size\x18\x01 \x01(\x03\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x02 \x01(\tB/\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x11TensorShapeProtosP\x01\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: just a guess: maybe you already had an old version of protobuf installed? maybe try pip installing with "-U" to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does look like a protobuf library versioning error. There's a long thread on similar issues here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11
Towards the end there are some suggested solutions that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed in running TensorFlow 0.7 on a manjaro linux laptop using cuda acceleration by running python with optirun:

```
$optirun python
```

However, I had problem with protobuf and I had to uninstall/reinstall previous version of protobuf and tensorflow with pip. [See this post](https://dip4fish.blogspot.com/2016/03/using-tensorflow-07-from-python-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of protobuf version conflict:
for me i had python-protobuf v2.6.1 installed from apt-get package manager
and while installing tensorflow it installed protobuf v3.3.0 from pip manager

so i uninstalled both:

```
sudo pip uninstall protobuf
sudo apt-get remove python-protobuf
```

Reinstalled using pip and it solved the issue!!!

```
sudo pip install protobuf
```

Hope this helps..